# Resizing a web page dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am developing a bunch of small web applications that have an unknown window size as target. To solve this problem, I am developing very large layouts and scaling them according to the window size.

My solution however has an inconvenience. When I resize everything, things get a little bit out of place (mainly when scaling text) and it is noticeable. My code is very simple, everything in my page is absolutely positioned so I just get the scaling factor and apply it to all the positions and width / height of every div/img/span/input in the page. The code is as follows:

```
function resize()
{
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var h = maxHeight;

    var ww = $(window).width();
    var w = maxWidth;

    var wProp = ww / w;
    var hProp = wh / h;

    if (wProp < hProp) prop = wProp;
    else prop = hProp;

    if (prop > 1) prop = 1;

    console.log(prop);
    $("div").each (applyNewSize);
    $("img").each (applyNewSize);
    $("span").each (applyNewSize);
    $("input").each (applyNewSize);
}
//this is run when the page is loaded
function initializeSize (i)
{
    this.oX = $(this).position().left;
    this.oY = $(this).position().top;
    this.oW = $(this).width();
    this.oH = $(this).height();
    if ($(this).css("font-size") != undefined)
    {
        this.oFS = Number($(this).css("font-size").split("px")[0]);
    }
}

function applyNewSize (i)
{
    if (this.oFS != undefined) $(this).css("font-size", Math.round(this.oFS * prop) + "px");
    $(this).css("left", Math.round(this.oX * prop) + "px");
    $(this).css("top", Math.round(this.oY * prop) + "px");
    $(this).width(Math.round(this.oW * prop));
    $(this).height(Math.round(this.oH * prop));
}
```

This problem has been tormenting me for the past week. Do you have any workaround or solution for this?

Comment: I seem to remember that the page for the Google Closure compier as having a javascript controlled footer. I.e it's positioned based on the window size. You could see worse examples of it than theirs, I guess. http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: Please read up on "responsive design". Many of these problems have already been solved.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use media queries ? and sizes in em ? and any other responsive best practices ?

Comment: @Bartdude Thanks for the replies, I have looked into responsive web design and I wonder if media queries are compatible with IE8 (it is one of the requirements for my applications). My font sizes already are in em, but how does it work?

Comment: Why not using mostly CSS for your dynamic desing and just javascript little correction when needed. Styling in percentage or EM with a min-width / max-width is, by experience, way more reliable than javascript. You can easily do dynamic layout with CSS2 (which is support even by IE7)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read about Responsive Web design.

It works putting % instead the exact pixels :

```
 <div class="container"> 
  <section>
    THIS IS THE SECTION
  </section>
</div>
```

CSS::

```
.container{
  width: 80%; // 80% instead pixels
  background: gainsboro;
  border: 3px inset darkgrey;
  height: 200px;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
}


section{

  width: 80%; // 80% instead pixels
  height: 80%; // 80% instead pixels
  background: darkgrey;
  margin:auto;


}
```

Then you can use media queries as well, to reallocate the blocks or applying different styles on different widths :

example tutorial :  http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/